# "could not find mediator" for XSLT Mediator when bulk publishing on Tridion 2009

Tags: publishing, xslt-mediator

I’m also getting this below error message when I did bulk publish pages or DCP components on Tridion 2009.

> JScriptException: Expression ‘RenderComponentPresentation()’ had error ‘Could not find mediator for template type: text/xml’

I did configure XLST mediator. When I publish one by one page or DCP, it's getting success. If I publish with child publication also option, it's getting failed.

If I preview no issue, mediator is working fine. If I publish bulk it’s getting failed. Only getting success one by one page publishing English and Arabic components.

I did integrate XSLT mediator, To added function for generate thumnail image cropping.
Wherever my page, or DCP, using this mediator it’s getting this issue when I publish bulk.

Please help us find this issue.

Comment: It's fixed now, Tridion publishing queue processed based on two server, So basically it's works here after CMS publish, publishing query got processed based on two server transport services. Hence second server we didn't updated XSLT mediator dll, 

Now I did updated the dll with second server and restarted the tridion services and COM+servies. It's working fine

Answer (score 3):

To have a clear understanding, I want to add some points to it

For all the Templating related (XSLT Mediator, Templating DLL, Dreamweaver Extension), we need to remember that

1. Register templating DLL into GAC on all

   - Content Managers
   - Publishers
2. Restart Tridion Content Manager COM+ server
3. Restart all the Tridion Publishers

Most of the clients uses more than one publisher, so there are chance to miss to register DLL into GAC